# using radio button to insert in database table using php

Tags: php, database, html, mysqli

I have this code and i want to insert the items inside the database but it is not inserting.
HTML5 code:

```
<form action="simple.php" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="games" value="1" size="20"<?php print $itemname;?
>Buy It</br>
<input type="Submit"name="Submit1" value="Add to cart"></center></a></div> 
</div></td></form>
```

php:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {

$selected_radio = $_POST['games'];

if ($selected_radio == '1') {

 $un ='checked';

if ($un='checked')

$value="whatever value";
$sql="INSERT INTO cartorders(id,item,price) VALUES ('$id','$value',250)";
$res=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql);
```

Comment: I don't get any error that's why I don't know my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Use `id` as an Auto Increment ID

```
   <?php

    if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
        $selected_radio = $_POST['games'];
        if ($selected_radio == '1') {
            $value = "whatever value";
            $sql   = "INSERT INTO cartorders(item,price) VALUES ('" . $value . "',250)";
            $res   = mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql);
        }
    }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If u are getting value for the $id, and it will be unique, then it should work. But as suggested, its better to make ID an Auto Increment field in your db c there will be issue while updating if you don't have a unique field.